# SQL compare 2 table datasets, return only exceptions / differences (reconciling)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

Looking for advice on the best way to datasets from 2 different tables, compare them, then only return the NAMES with BALANCE differences.

For example, here are my tables:

```
Table A
NAME       STATE      CITY        COMPANY     BALANCE
Joe        CA         San Diego   xyz         100
John       CA         San Diego   abc         50
Jim        CA         Los Angeles xyz         35

Table B
NAME       STATE      CITY        COMPANY     BALANCE
Joe        CA         San Diego   xyz         75
John       CA         San Diego   abc         50
Jim        CA         Los Angeles xyz         40
```

I'd like to return:

```
NAME       STATE      CITY        COMPANY     DIFFERENCE
Joe        CA         San Diego   xyz         25
Jim        CA         Los Angeles xyz         5
```

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple inner join will work fine here

```
SELECT 
   t1.Name,
   t1.State,
   t1.City,
   ABS(t1.Balance - t2.Balance

FROM 
   Table1  t1
   INNER JOIN Table2 t2
   ON t1.Name = t2.Name
     and t1.State = t2.State
     and t1.City = t2.City
     and t1.Company = t2.Company
WHERE
   t1.Balance <> t2.Balanace
```

Some notes

- You may have to add some null processing depending on what your business rules are.
- You may also want to consider using an outer join and moving the where clause to the join 
  if you want to include rows that are in one but not the other